# Find the 4 best parameters of a function to have the best cumulative sum

Tags: python, performance

I have a dataframe `data` with several columns and for each columns there are 10 years of daily data on average, something around 4000 rows then. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Date           A       B      C    ...
YYYY-MM-DD   123.4   56.7   89.0
YYYY-MM-DD   12.34   -5.6    NaN
...
```

Date is `datetime64`, every value is a `float` (positive and negative, they are real numbers), there could be `NaN`, there are no upside or downside boundaries.

I have this function :

```
def fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c, param_d):
    
    df = data.loc[(data[name_a].notnull()) & (data[name_b].notnull()),[name_a, name_b]]
    
    df_corr = pd.DataFrame()
    df_corr[name_a] = df[name_a]
    df_corr[name_b] = df[name_b].shift(param_a)
    print(df_corr.corr().iloc[0,1])
    
    df['pct'] = df[name_a].pct_change() 
    df['name_b_delta'] = df[name_b].shift(2+param_a)-df[name_b].shift(2+param_a+param_b)
    df['is_ok'] = df['name_b_delta'].apply(lambda x : np.sign(x+(-param_c)))
    
    if param_d:
        df['results'] = df['is_ok'] * (-1) * df['pct'] 
    else:
        df['results'] = df['is_ok'] * df['pct'] 
        
    df['cumul_results'] = df['results'].cumsum()             
                                                  
    return df
```

and currently, to optimize the `cumul_results` for differents pairs of `name_a` and `name_b`, I search for the best params using those nested loops :

```
name_a_list = ['a_dozen_of_elements_here']
name_b_list= ['25_elements_here']

df_line= []
df_index = []

for name_a in name_a_list :
    for name_b in name_b_list :
        for param_a in range(0,15):
            for param_b in range(1,15):
                for param_c in range (-2, 3, 1):
                    for param_d in [True, False]:
                        df = fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c/1000, param_d):
                        df_index.append(f"{name_a}-{name_b}")
                        df_line.append([df['cumul_results'].iloc[-1], param_a, param_b, param_c, param_d])

results = pd.DataFrame(index=df_index, data=df_line, columns=['final result', 'param_a', 'param_b', 'param_c', 'param_d'])
```

It's more than 840 000 calls of the function `fct` and takes around 4 hours. I was wondering then if I could increase the performance of this code to reduce time. Thanks !

Comment: You're doing exhaustive search which is the "last resort" of numerical optimization. How smooth are your data? How likely is it that a more traditional numerical optimizer would find a false positive on a local minimum?

Comment: `name_b_list` contains columns with relatively (~30 days rolling) smoothed data but not `name_a_list` (stocks prices). I would say that for `param_a` and `param_b` maybe we could do the loop with a step of 2, but a bigger step could miss some results i would have selected i think, that's why i did the exhaustive way.

Comment: It's also worth saying that this is precariously close to running afoul of the 'hypothetical code' policy of CR. All of your column names are clearly placeholders; `data` is undefined; and so this code will not run as-is. I can guess my way through but that's not going to do you any favours. If possible just use the actual column names, etc.

Comment: p.s. the colon at the end of the `df = fct` statement furthers the idea that this is hypothetical code, will not execute, and is difficult to review.

Comment: Yet another thing missing is what's actually done with `results`. It's difficult to see how this is serving the purpose of finding the four best parameters.

Comment: How is this calling the function 840,000 times? 12*25*15*14*5*2 == 630,000.

Comment: It's hypothetical code regarding the variable names but it's the same code i use, I can't write the real names in regard to the company where i work, but it doesn't change the idea i guess ? I'm just trying to find the best parameter to optimize the results of `fct`. For the number of calling i wrote a dozen for `name_a_list` because it can vary a bit and when i count it was with more elements.

Comment: I downvoted your question because I've read your question twice on two different occasions and I still don't have a clue what you're doing. I've salvaged many a bad question before, but I can't make heads of your question. What does your code do, please ELI5?

Comment: @Peilonrayz it creates some signal based on the difference of value between two days of `name_b`. But the value of the signal and the value of the difference differ in regard to the params value, so it impacts the final results because i multiply the signal to the column `name_a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer, part one**

It looks like about half the loops can be avoided by doing the `True` and `False` cases at the same time.  These differ only by the multiplication by -1 at the end of `fct`.  That suggests that results of of a `True` invocation can be used to shortcut the computations of the immediately following invocation of `fct`.

Is there a reason to not cache the results of the several array accesses?  That is, for example, `df[name_a]`, `df[name_b]`, and others?

Can the `apply` and `lambda` be avoided?  This seems overly complex (meaning, slow) way to perform the computation.

I presume the `print` invocation is not there usually.  IO in the inner loop would slow things down considerably.

**Answer, part 2**

Sample code.  This runs for me, but I haven't verified that it produces exactly the same results.

I made two kinds of updates: Values which were shared across loops were lifted to the most common loop.  The `True` and `False` cases were collapsed into a single function call which returns the `True` and `False` results using multiple values.

Ignore my comment re: apply.

My gut tells me that at least the innermost `shift` invocation ought to be unnecessary, but I haven't figured how to write a correct `apply` that would remove it.  (I need the apply iteration index to be passed in as an extra parameter.)

I added a number of print statements for debugging which you will want to remove.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

def fct_tf(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c, df_common, df_shift):
    "Compute results for two sets of parameters"

    df_false = df_common.copy()

    # Lift one of the shifts up a loop.
    # Still working on removing the shifts altogether.
    # df_false['name_b_delta'] = df_false[name_b].shift(2+param_a)-df_false[name_b].shift(2+param_a+param_b)
    df_false['name_b_delta'] = df_shift - df_shift.shift(param_b)
    df_false['is_ok'] = df_false['name_b_delta'].apply(lambda x : np.sign(x+(-param_c)))

    df_false['results'] = df_false['is_ok'] * df_false['pct']
    df_false['cumul_results'] = df_false['results'].cumsum()

    df_true = df_false.copy()
    df_true['results'] = -1 * df_false['results']
    df_true['cumul_results'] = -1 * df_false['cumul_results']

    return df_true, df_false

def fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c, param_d):
    "Compute results for one set of parameters"

    df = data.loc[(data[name_a].notnull()) & (data[name_b].notnull()),[name_a, name_b]]

    df['pct'] = df[name_a].pct_change() 
    df['name_b_delta'] = df[name_b].shift(2+param_a)-df[name_b].shift(2+param_a+param_b)
    df['is_ok'] = df['name_b_delta'].apply(lambda x : np.sign(x+(-param_c)))

    if param_d:
        df['results'] = df['is_ok'] * (-1) * df['pct'] 
    else:
        df['results'] = df['is_ok'] * df['pct'] 

    df['cumul_results'] = df['results'].cumsum()             
                                                  
    return df

def compute(data, names_a, names_b):
    "Compute results ..."

    df_line= []
    df_index = []

    for name_a in names_a :
        print('name_a: ' + name_a)
        for name_b in names_b :
            print('name_b: ' + name_b)

            # 'df_common' will have just one column if the names are the same.
            # Then, an exception occurs when invoking 'pct_change()'.
            if ( name_a == name_b ):
                continue

            # This part of the results data is common across the parameters.
            df_common = data.loc[(data[name_a].notnull()) & (data[name_b].notnull()),[name_a, name_b]]
            print('Common data:')
            print(df_common)

            # The percent change is also common.  Note that the values are not free from
            # a dependence on 'name_b', since the null check can change which rows are selected.
            # That means this value cannot be lifted to the 'name_a' loop.
            df_common['pct'] = df_common[name_a].pct_change()
            print("Common data[pct]:")
            print(df_common['pct'])

            for param_a in range(0,15):
                # Reduce the number of shifts
                # In theory, this shift should be avoidable, but I'm still figuring
                # how to remove it.
                df_shift = df_common[name_b].shift(2+param_a)

                for param_b in range(1,15):
                    for param_c in range (-2, 3, 1):
                        # The computations for 'False' and 'True' are the same, except
                        # for a change in sign.
                        # for param_d in [True, False]:
                            # df = fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c/1000, param_d)
                            # df_index.append(f"{name_a}-{name_b}")
                            # df_line.append([df['cumul_results'].iloc[-1], param_a, param_b, param_c, param_d])

                        df_true, df_false = fct_tf(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c/1000, df_common, df_shift)

                        df_index.append(f"{name_a}-{name_b}")
                        df_line.append([df_true['cumul_results'].iloc[-1], param_a, param_b, param_c, True])

                        df_index.append(f"{name_a}-{name_b}")
                        df_line.append([df_false['cumul_results'].iloc[-1], param_a, param_b, param_c, False])

    results = pd.DataFrame(index=df_index, data=df_line, columns=['final result', 'param_a', 'param_b', 'param_c', 'param_d'])

    return results
```

Comment: For the first point you mean doing something like `df_true = fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c/1000, True)` and  `df_false = fct(data, name_a, name_b, param_a, param_b, param_c/1000, False)` just after `param_c in range (-2, 3, 1):`?
What do you mean by "not to cache" ? For the `apply` and `lambda`, i thought vectorization was the fastest ? And yes `print` is just a check I added after but it was not in the search of parameters.

Comment: Try putting the code within `fct(..., True)` next to the code within `fct(..., False)`, and see how much of the computation is repeated.

Comment: Yes i see your point, so it would be better to output before the `param_d` check and then append `True` and `False` value at the same time ? Could you write an example for the caching results thing you mentionned ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your edit with the code, there are pertinent changes. Let me know if you find for the `shift` and `apply` things, thanks !

Comment: Something to consider: If the print out can display the common data just once, then display the results for each of the parameter combinations, then copies of the common data can be avoided, which should save both time and resources.